java otel configuration error opentelemetry-exporter-otlp not found on classpath
I have definced following dependecies for otel in my java apache flink project:
flinkShadowJar (platform("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-bom:1.35.0"));
flinkShadowJar ("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-api");
flinkShadowJar ("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk");
flinkShadowJar ("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-logging");
flinkShadowJar ("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp");
flinkShadowJar ("io.opentelemetry.semconv:opentelemetry-semconv:1.24.0-alpha");
flinkShadowJar ("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure");

But am getting following error when deploying flink pipeline:
"errors":["org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Could not execute application.
Caused by: io.opentelemetry.sdk.autoconfigure.spi.ConfigurationException: otel.metrics.exporter set to "otlp" but opentelemetry-exporter-otlp not found on classpath. Make sure to add it as a dependency.
I want my app to deploy, and also the open telemetry to produce traces, which I configured manually in my app.

It looks like removing this import fixed the issue:
flinkShadowJar ("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-logging");
